# ASP.NET MVC - Can't use HTML Raw inside Foreach Loop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml page and in this page I have a foreach razor for a Viewbag and I want to use HTML.Raw in a viewbad item.
I tried @Html.raw and Html.raw and they both give me the error.

When I try to use it, it gives me this error "Encountered end tag "div" and encounters the end tag errors.

```
 @foreach (var div in ViewBag.teste)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="box box-success">
                                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                                            <h3 class="box-title">Por <b>@div.UtilizadorAct</b>  na data de <b>@div.Data</b></h3>
                                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.box-tools  (ViewBag.teste as List<ModelLayer.Entities.GTarefas.TicketUpdate>)-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                                        <div class="box-body">
                                          <div class="row">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                WHERE GIVES THE ERROR     Html.Raw(@div.Descricao)
                                                  </ div >
                                              </ div >
                                            < div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Anexos:</label>
                                                    @*@div.path*@
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                                    </div>  




                                </div>
                            }
```

I need some help in this matter

Comment: That should be `@Html.Raw(div.Descricao)`, notice how @ is used. Did you try that?

Comment: yes and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing `@Html.Raw(div.Descricao)` and fixing the spacing with the end div tags below the `Html.Raw` call? So, change the tags `</ div >` to `</div>` and `< div class="row">` to `<div class="row">`